# Defining a function from an evaluated function stored in a variable

Tags: function-construction, assignment

I have the evaluation of a function `b`, stored in `appo`. Now I want to define a new function `f` (actually the same as `b`) using `appo`, as in the code below, which does not work.

```
b[s_] := s^2
appo = b[t]
f[t_] := appo;
f[2]
b[2]
(*
 t^2
 t^2
 4
*)
```

Note that instead

```
b[s_] := s^2
appo = b[t]
f[t_] := b[t];
f[2]
b[2]
(*
 t^2
 4
 4
*)
```

works perfectly. Do I miss something important about how Mathematica handles parameters? What is the problem with the first version?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrap `appo` with `Evaluate`: `f[t_] := Evaluate[appo];`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I think I see the problem.

Comment: You can also do `f[t_] = appo` instead